# Getting Zipcode using GPS android

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I am developing an application where I need to find zipcode using GPS. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into using Geocoder. Specifically [`Geocoder.getFromLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29).

Once you get the List of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)(es) you can get the zip code from those Address(es) using [`Address.getPostalCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for a location using the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and then use the received location to send a reverse geocoding request with [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).