# Is it possible to get the zip code of my current location with mobile google maps sensor?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am currently using google maps in my mobile page to show the current location of the mobile user via gps on a map.

Is it somehow possible to get the zip code of the current location of the user using google maps api?

Any examples of how this could work would be great :)

Then i could insert this zip code in a different search :)

Greets and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you can do it by referring here:[getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29),and after that,you can get a list of Address,and then by referring this [getPostalCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode%28%29) .You may has found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375884/getting-zipcode-using-gps-android) post out earlier!

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I want to get the postal code with the google maps api and not with android. is this possible, too?
Greets

Comment: @RubenSchulze-Fröhlich  refer to [Geocoding API](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1), and the postal code part.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this question and check my answer this will help you :

[Get the particular address using latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515682/get-the-particular-address-using-latitude-and-longitude/16515848#16515848)